# ORDER BY result of SQL query

Tags: php, sql, sorting, inner-join

I have two tables:

'posts' (where 'post_text' field rows are comments users have posted); and
'votes' (the users' votes (thumbs up/down) on the posts, where 'post_id' matches 'id' from the 'posts' table):

```
SELECT *
FROM  `posts` 

+----+-----------+
| id | post_text |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | test0     |
|  2 | test1     |
|  3 | test2     |
|  4 | test3     |
|  5 | test4     |
|  6 | test5     |
|  7 | test6     |
|  8 | test7     |
|  9 | test8     |
| 10 | test9     |
| 11 | test10    |
+----+-----------+

SELECT *
FROM  `votes`

+----+---------+--------+
| id | post_id | rating |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |       2 |      0 |
|  3 |       4 |      1 |
|  4 |       4 |      1 |
|  5 |       6 |      1 |
|  6 |       6 |      1 |
|  7 |       7 |      0 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

What I'd like to do is get all the 'post_text' values from 'posts' table, but sort them by highest no. of thumbs-up ('1') ratings first, then thumbs-downs ('0') to come next, then the posts without ratings (i.e. no corresponding votes in the 'votes' table) to come last. With a join, I can achieve this but I don't know how to get the 'post_text' values without ratings to also be in the result. This is what I got:

```
SELECT posts.id, post_id, rating, COUNT( * ) 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.post_id
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY rating DESC , COUNT( * ) DESC , post_id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30

+----+---------+--------+----------+
| id | post_id | rating | COUNT(*) |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
|  6 |       6 |      1 |        2 |
|  4 |       4 |      1 |        2 |
|  1 |       1 |      1 |        1 |
|  7 |       7 |      0 |        1 |
|  2 |       2 |      0 |        1 |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Change your `INNER JOIN` to be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`(`LEFT JOIN` for short).

Comment: Wow, that was simple... thanks. Now how would I print out duplicate values? E.g. where the COUNT is 2, print the two rows instead

Comment: Think I got it: GROUP BY posts.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.post_text, post_id, rating, COUNT( * ) 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.post_id
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY rating DESC , COUNT( * ) DESC , post_id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```